# How to make sure that a network request was sent with Qt 5?

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm using `QNetworkAccessManager` to send HTTP GET/POST requests. Sometimes I would like to send a request immediately before closing the application. There is no need for me to wait for the server reply. But when I do that, the request doesn't seem to get through.

After calling `get()`, how can I make sure that the request was sent before destroying the application?

Comment: Could you show what you tried?

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried reading the documentation, and now I'm reading the source. Not sure how to show that? :)

Comment: try with finished signal or isFinished() or isRunning() of QNetworkReply

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you for trying to help. From looking at the source, it doesn't seem like they expose this information in the public API. So the answer might very well be "not possible".

Comment: `isFinished()` simply returns `!isRunning()`. `isFinished()` returns true only after the client has finished receiving all data from the server. Which is not what I want.